# asp.net panel default button not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have 2 panels on an asp.net page. I have a login and register panel, and I have set the `DefaultButton="btn1` property for each of the panels. If you complete the either form (and focused in that form) it always fires off the register button, which is the first button/panel on the page. Here is my code below:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlRegister" DefaultButton="btn1">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="Email" ID="txtEmail" placeholder="Email" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="Password" ID="txtPass" placeholder="Password" /> <br /><br />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn1" OnClick="Register" Text="Register" />
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlLogin" DefaultButton="btn2">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmailLog" placeholder="Email Address" /> <br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="Password" ID="txtPassLog" placeholder="Password" /> <br /> <br />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn2" OnClick="Login" Text="Login" />
</asp:Panel>
```

EDIT FOR DETAIL:

There is no error, it simply isn't working as it's supposed to. 
The `DefaultButton` attribute is supposed to submit the default button when 'enter' is typed while focused on a field inside the panel. For instance, when trying to use the login boxes on the `pnlLogin` panel and press enter, the `btn1` button is submitted (which is the Register function) instead of the `btn2` (which is the Login function).

I hope that helps clear confusion instead of adding to it.

Comment: what is the error here ? and what are you looking out for ? its _unclear_. You need to show the code-behind also reference

Comment: The error is stated above in that the `DefaultButton` attribute isn't working on the second panel, specifically. The code behind shouldn't have any bearing on this attribute working or not.

Comment: what is the error? can you us the full code

Comment: There is no error text. It's just not working like it's supposed to with the `DefaultButton` attribute on the panels as seen above:
`<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlLogin" DefaultButton="btn2">`

The attribute is supposed to submit the default button when 'enter' is typed while focused on a field inside the panel. For instance, when trying to use the login boxes on the `pnlLogin` panel and press enter, the `btn1` button is submitted (which is the Register function) instead of the `btn2` (which is the Login function).

Answer (score 0):

Change your Buttons to:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="true" ID="btn1" OnClick="Register" Text="Register" />
<asp:Button runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="true" ID="btn2" OnClick="Login" Text="Login" />
```

UseSubmitBehavior makes your button react on submit action (clicking enter) corresponding to your code, now your code reacts by browser's default style.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but that did not seem to work for me. I added the `UseSubmitBehavior="true"` on both buttons, but it's still only submitting the first panel.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't a solution, and I'm still looking for one, but to bypass the issue I ended up hiding one of the panels and switching between the forms depending on the function the user wants to complete. If I find a better solution, I'll post back here.